# Software using google API returns incorrect information

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I've been having an issue generating a geocode map of a large list of postcodes (~29,000) online, and finally found a site named 'EasyMapMaker'. It seemed to work fine, although took a very long time as expected, but a great number of postcodes are not in the correct location.

When entering these postcodes into google maps, they are not recognised or incorrect. I assume then that the errors in EasyMapMaker, which uses the Google geocoding API, are related to google.

My question is, Is there an alternative free software with a large data limit that functions off of something other than the Google Geocoding API, and is likely to be faster with less margin of error?

Comment: Is this for a specific country or global?

Comment: I'm trying to make a Global geocode map, although if there was software where the scope was confined just to the UK that would still be incredibly useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the UK Ordnance Survey offer a free dataset which is updated quarterly, called [Code-Point Open](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html), this would give you "street level" geocoding meaning that the location information would match the postcode rather than each individual address. They also make this available as an [API](http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/lookup).

For global geocoding then you could look at [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/geocoding/), which uses Open Street Map data so the coverage depends on how much data people have contributed.